# How do I get the namespace prefix?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

Is there a way to get the namespace prefix from a class or class instance (an object not XML)? For example, in MXML you could declare something as s:Button or local:MyComponent. Is there some call or approach that will return the "s" or "local" value when given the object?

For example, if I have the class TextInput and I wanted to show the style inheritance at runtime I could do something like this:

```
s|TextInput {

   fontFamily:Arial;
}

s|TextArea#myTextArea {

   color:red;

}

local|MyComponent.myBoldStyle {
   fontWeight: bold;

}
```

Comment: You define the prefixes yourself at the top of the document. They could be anything you want. It doesn't _have_ to be `s` or `local`. What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: These are compile time values; and nothing you'll be able to do at runtime will get you these values.  Unless you load up your source code as an XML Document and process it as XML.

Comment: Well I've figured out how to lookup the style inheritance and so I'd like to be able to show the CSS type declarations for the class with s|TextInput or local|MyComponent when tracing them out to the console. I'll be uploading the class util if you guys are interested (or posting it here to the other question I posted).

Comment: What @www.Flextras.com suggested goes for CSS documents too: I believe your only option is to parse the CSS file.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com - can you add your comment as an answer? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespaces are compile time values.  You won't be able to retrieve these values at runtime unless you load up your source code as an XML Document and process it as XML